# SQLite Trigger, Convert OLD/NEW to TEXT

Tags: sqlite, database-trigger

How to convert SQLite trigger variables `OLD`/`NEW` to `TEXT` or if possible a JSON object?
I want to log every changes to another table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.

OLD and NEW are not "trigger variables"; they are keywords that can be used in column references, such as OLD.*columnname*.

If you want to log changes of the column values, you have to write out all the columns of the table in each trigger.

Comment: I know this is a silly question, but is the situation the same today? Are `old` and `new` still just keywords, or do they now have semantic structure to help us encode them as JSON?

Comment: @AhmedFasih Nothing has changed in this regard.